# I am getting a strange compiling error (arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

Here are the errors:

> core.a(main.cpp.o): In function 'main':
>   
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/main.cpp:11: >
> undefined reference to 'setup'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/main.cpp:14: >
> undefined reference to 'loop'

I cannot seem to figure it out.
here is the code.

```
void setup(int x, int y) //make joystick arcade style controller
{
int powY;
int powX;
int powRightMotor;
int powLeftMotor;
int powmotordriveright;
int powmotordriveleft;

// convert joystick -128 to 127 range to -100 to 100 for powering motors
powY = (y * 100) / 127; //joystick y axis gives maximum power level
powX = (x * 100) / 127; //x axis determines which motor is reduced or
//reversed for a turn

for
if (powX < 0) //if x negative, turning left; otherwise, turning right
{
powLeftMotor = (powY * (100 + (2 * powX))/100); //left motor reduced for right turn
powRightMotor = (powY * -(100 + (2 * powX))/100); //right motor is reversed
}
else
{
powRightMotor = (powY * (100 - (2 * powX))/100); //right motor reduced for left turn
powLeftMotor = (powY * -(100 + (2 * powX))/100); //left motor reversed
}

powRightMotor = powmotordriveright;
powLeftMotor = powmotordriveleft;
}
loop;
```

Comment: Where did you learn the `for ... loop;` syntax?

Answer (score 4):

You really need to start from the beginning.  Learn the blink program first so you understand how the Arduino works and interacts with the code that you give it.

look at this picture for example

[image: Arduino Blink]

Create the [`setup()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Setup) Method (without parameters) and setup all the pins you need, then create a [`loop()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Loop) method that will loop and take the input from the pins and output to the pins at a set interval.

Please look at the links throughout this answer, I think that you will find them helpful.

---

You should have something like this instead

```
void setup() //make joystick arcade style controller
{
    //Joystick input you may need more depending on the 
    //device that you are using
    pinMode(13, INPUT);
    pinMode(14, INPUT); 
    //output pins to the motors
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    //

}

void loop()
{
    int powY;
    int powX;
    int y = analogRead(13); // you could also set your pins to variables
    int x = analogRead(14); // and probably should for readability

    int powRightMotor;
    int powLeftMotor;
    int powmotordriveright;
    int powmotordriveleft;

    // convert joystick -128 to 127 range to -100 to 100 for powering motors
    powY = (y * 100) / 127; //joystick y axis gives maximum power level
    powX = (x * 100) / 127; //x axis determines which motor is reduced or
    //reversed for a turn


    if (powX < 0) //if x negative, turning left; otherwise, turning right
    {
        powLeftMotor = (powY * (100 + (2 * powX))/100); //left motor reduced for right turn
        powRightMotor = (powY * -(100 + (2 * powX))/100); //right motor is reversed
    }
    else
    {
        powRightMotor = (powY * (100 - (2 * powX))/100); //right motor reduced for left turn
        powLeftMotor = (powY * -(100 + (2 * powX))/100); //left motor reversed
    }

    powRightMotor = powmotordriveright;
    powLeftMotor = powmotordriveleft;

    //you are going to want to transform the value to something between 0-255 for an analogWrite
    //it's been a while since I worked with arduinos and wrote the actual code, and I don't know
    //what you are working with either.

    analogWrite(11, powRightMotor);
    analogWrite(12, powLeftMotor
}
```

in this case we don't need the for loop because the `loop()` method already does this "out of the box".  so we just check all the input and translate the values to run the motors.

I probably slaughtered this because I don't know what kind of hardware setup that you have going on, but I am pretty sure this should compile

To run on the Arduino platform you absolutely need these 2 Methods, Arduinos are picky.

---

should you need to setup an infinite loop using a for loop it would be structured like this

```
for (;;)
{
    //do work here
}
```

putting `loop;` doesn't do anything, it is a syntax error.

(Reference [Arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ForLoop) for proper for loop structure)

A While loop might be better for an infinite loop though, then you can set a boolean, and have it exit in certain cases.  Having an inescapable loop is not a good idea.

Comment: `for (;;)` is shorter, clearer and doesn't introduce an unused variable.

Comment: I will change that, thank you. I don't purposely create infinite loops...lol

Comment: Thanks!! but, it doesn't work still it shows this: core.a(main.cpp.o): In function `main':
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `setup'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `loop'

Comment: @Nickdacreeper What do you expect `loop;` to do?!

Comment: look at my Edit, you need to start with `setup()` no parameters and `loop()`

Comment: I'm a noob srry. I'm trying to fix stuff in the code my team has

Comment: like I said, check out the Site I have been linking to.  Arduino is not entirely  C++ it is based on C++ and the hardware needs the code structured a certain way to work. there is also an http://arduino.stackexchange.com/  site in Beta.  feel free to read the Help page there and see if it can help you by perusing the Questions and Answers

Comment: i incorporated it all but it still give me this and i am experienced enough to be offended by you showing me Blink.

Comment: not experienced enough to know that you aren't setting up the basic Methods properly. you can't call `setup()` inside of itself, and you can't call `setup();` without parameters if you forced the Method to take parameters. because you haven't defined the method to take no parameters.